# Installing PhoneGap 1.5 templates for Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I want to develop an app for windows phone using Phone Gap. The Phone Gap webpage indicates this in the installation instructions page (http://phonegap.com/start#wp):

*Download the latest copy of PhoneGap and extract its contents. Navigate to the Windows Phone directory and copy the file **PhoneGapStarter.zip** to your templates folde*

But in the current version THERE IS NO PHONEGAPSTARTER.ZIP file, so I can't install the Visual Studio templates, and so I can't create PhoneGapp apps on WP7. :-(

Anyone has had the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these links. callback-windows-phone is now moved to below links

https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8

https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8/blob/master/README.md

Hope this will help you out.

From the first link download & copy the file Cordova-1.5.0-Starter.zip to the folder : \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\

Comment: the link has been updated again to http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-windows-phone

Comment: @carbonr 3 links are 404. I wonder why they moved it so frequently?

Answer (score 1):

The PhoneGap project has been renamed to Cordova, however, the docs have not been updated. Download the zip file, then locate the following file from within this zip:

```
 lib\windows\Cordova-1.5.0-Starter.zip
```

And add that to your project templates directory

Answer (score -1):

I had to log out/in to Windows (not just restart Visual Studio) before the CordovaStarter was listed under Installed Templates/Visual C#/Silver Light for Windows Phone.